# CCL breaks over illegal characters in file/directory name?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, ccl

Consider the following:

```
(directory (make-pathname :directory '(:absolute "Users" "gazonk" "foo" "*")
                          :name :wild))
```

This breaks because one of the directories contains the character ";".

If the "*" above is removed, the code returns a directory listing where ";" is escaped.

It seems I cannot make it go further down because some directories contain a ";"

Is there a fix for this?

Any and all commends appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There are bugs with CCL and handling ; in file names. You should report that. Btw., instead of "*" use :wild .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed.  I see the same behavior with ccl 1.9 (64-bit or 32-bit) on Mac OS X 10.8.

I created an empty subdirectory using mkdir 'a;b' and I see:

```
(make-pathname :directory '(:absolute "Users" "gazonk" "foo" "*") :name :wild))
> Error: Illegal directory string "/Users/gazonk/foo/a;b/"
> While executing: CCL::%DIRECTORY-STRING-LIST, in process listener(1).
```

**Update:**

Based on Rainer's comment, it sounds like this is likely a ccl bug.

Recommend asking on the #ccl irc channel or submitting a bug report [here](http://trac.clozure.com/ccl/newticket) (requires registration).

Comment: Logical pathnames are not really connected to that. CCL just plain has a bug and fails to create a pathname from a physical file.